# What are the generic standards to obtain clean proper AC mains input

Tags: ac, protection

I'm confused with choosing a generic topology for mains surge protection and chokes. I cannot find a good overview explanation on the topic. My question might sound not so specific but I cannot understand the big picture since there are many variants.

Here lets look at couple of examples:

[image]

[image]

Is there standard generic topology for surge, transient and over current protection?

Is there a single AC mains connector in the market which provides all? Well I can myself at least install the fuse across the hot line. But imagine you have a device outdoors and you want to suppress overvoltages transients all sorts of problems. There are chokes, there are NTC, there are MOV ect ect.

What is your favourite topology when building an electronic box which will stay outdoors prone to over voltages ect. Imagine you just built a box with some electrical circuit in it and the AC mains will feed your DC adapter inside which will supply energy to electronics circuitry. Imagine the max current you want to limit is 2A. I would be glad to see your example diagram for this purpose. Diagram how one provide a safe proper input to DC adapter from AC mains. I would like to see how the suppression and other possible issues eliminated in a generic way.  An example diagram helps to understand.

Comment: There isn't a generic standard and asking for one is probably too broad, because the range of mains powered appliances is so broad. In the last paragraph you're starting to ask a more specific question, but it's still unclear what you're trying to protect. As to the schematics shown ... if they don't spell "appliance" correctly, do you trust them as protection?

Comment: Switch mode AC to DC converters are tricky to design, and it is kind of a specialty application. I would not undertake to design one. I would buy one (possibly slightly customized) from a known vendor. I think that is what you should do, too. If you are worried about lightning, you can look into lightning protection as a separate topic. Where I live, lightning is very rare, so I don't have much experience with it.

Comment: @mkeith Pardon my ignorance; so are you saying the SMPS supplies already provides the protections I mentioned? I wasn't planning to build a power supply which is the expertise of power electronics as you mentioned. Because sometimes I still see choke filters right after mains(between mains and the DC power supply). I guess you mean the surge protection is builtin in modern adapters right?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your intention. I believe you should be able to find an AC-DC supply which already incorporates the necessary level of surge protection. If you are in an area where lightning is a concern, you may want to research lightning protection since you said this unit will be outdoors.